# How to send local image file via an api to parse.com?

Tags: image, api, parse-platform, upload, profile

I am trying to build up a web application with javascript and nodejs. In order to hide the ApplicationID/Key, I use API to handle the data saving.

For example, if I need to save a object on Parse. Instead of using Parse Javascript SDK on the client side, I send the object to the server and then ask server to save the parse.

Everything was working fine until I try to upload images to the server. It turns out I need to somehow upload the images to server before I can save these images to parse class because PFFile need urls to upload the images. But the image at this time is still in local. I was thinking to convert image to base64 string and then server can convert it back to image data and then save it to the parse. However, I didn't succeed with this approach. Can anyone provides some insight? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When uploading a image, you can just use

```
uploadImg(photo):void{
   var parseFile = new Parse.File("image.png", {base64:photo});
   parseFile.save();
}
```

the parameter photo is base64.

*Are you using AWS s3 to store your images?

Comment: Thanks, Lyon. I figured it out 10 mins after I posted this question. But still much thanks